# Black Screen without nomodeset

Tags: kernel, amd-graphics, amdgpu, nomodeset, amdgpu-pro

So i installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my PC 
Ryzen 3 1200
Radeon RX 560
Motherboard Biostar

it wont boot without nomodeset command, it will boot only with that command but graphic perfomance are realy poor, its blinking sometimes when i play videos, its just not working properly

i tried to install AMD Gpu driver but after i reboot it give me more error, now ubuntu refuse to boot even with nomodeset,
without nomodeset it will show only black screen 
now its stuck on 'Started User Manager for UID 121......edel.....rvuce....d before the ppp link was shut down ...

Comment: So, what did you do?